# NEST2: How to specify the db index name once

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, nest2

Our C# WebAPI application uses of an ElasticSearch database. We're using NEST2 to access the db.

All the NEST2 queries in the code specify the database index name, here an example:

```
public TestQuery[] GetAllDocuments()
{
    var readRecords = ec.Search<TestDocument>(s => s
        .Index("my-index-name")
        .Query(q => q.
            QueryString(qs => qs.Query("*")))).Documents;

    return readRecords.ToArray();
}
```

Sometimes we forget to specify the index name in the query... the problem doesn't manifest itself immediately as the API works as expected and everything is fine... only when we add another index with some similar documents in it we see the problem

Is it possible to specify the index name once for all after NEST2 initialization? Doing so I'll avoid the burden to remember to insert it on every single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `.DefaultIndex` method on `ConnectionSettings`.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings()
    .DefaultIndex("defaultindex");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at aliases:
[Index Alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-aliases.html)

So when you have a new index with similar documents you can add one alias after you create it and in the query in index name you specify the alias. In this way you can query 1 to multiple indexes using same name.
Hope it helps! If you need more info, write a comment.